# Have to Restart Apache When Using Django On Apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, restart

I'm creating a web app with Django. Since I'm very familiar with Apache I setup my development environment to have Django run through Apache using mod_wsgi. The only annoyance I have with this is that I have to restart Apache everytime I change my code. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I have a fastcgi setup, and I've found that `touch`ing the index.fcgi file helps; e.g. `touch public_html/sitename/index.fcgi` . I'm assuming there's a similar file that you can `touch` in wsgi.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

mod_wsgi is great for production but I think the included server is better for development.

Anyway you should read [this](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode) about automatic reloading of source code.

Comment: And for a Django slant on it, also read 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2008/12/using-modwsgi-when-developing-django.html' and 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/02/source-code-reloading-with-modwsgi-on.html'.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, looks like your links are busted.

Comment: Remove the quote at the end of the URL. SO has screwed up when picking out the URL.

Comment: (Corrected links): [Source code reloading with mod_wsgi on Windows](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/02/source-code-reloading-with-modwsgi-on.html) and [Using mod_wsgi when developing Django sites](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2008/12/using-modwsgi-when-developing-django.html).

Answer (score -4):

I feel like this is really just one of those things most people deal with. It's really not that big of a deal. I made a bash script to make this as easy as possible. I name it 'ra' (reload apache) so it's short and quick. The following works for most apache installs (on UNIX-based systems):

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

You could probably use some kind of tool to bind this to a key shortcut/foot pedeal/cron.

Comment: You could also do an alias that calls the same thing

Comment: I think that should be a comment, not a response, because it is a non-solution to the problem. You could avoid some down-voting that way as well while still getting the message across.